# Error when using PUT in a Macro variable (loop) SAS

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I need to have a variable with size 2 and leading zeros, such as 01, 02, 10, 11..., to I use in a macro.
The macro executa1 works, but shows the values ​​1,2,10,11 .... (without the zero).
So I tried to use the z2. format, like macro executa2.

But unfortunately, it doesn't work.

```
%LET vdia = 01;
%LET vano = 2019;

%MACRO executa1;
    %DO i=1 %TO 12 %BY 1;
        %LET vmes = &i;      
        %PUT &vmes;
    %END;
%MEND;

%MACRO executa2;
    %DO i=1 %TO 12 %BY 1;
        %LET vmes = %PUT(&i, z2.);
        %PUT &vmes;
    %END;
%MEND;

%executa1
%executa2
```

Log with error (executa2):

```
39              %LET vmes = %PUT(&i, z2.);
ERROR: Macro keyword PUT appears as text.
ERROR: A dummy macro will be compiled.
```

I also tried some combinations of **%eval()** and **%sysfunc()**, but to no avail.

Would anyone know any tips to achieve the expected result?

Comment: `%PUT` is a macro statement.  You can not assign a variable a statement.  You assign a variable a value, a resolvable expression, macro resolution or macro invocation that may or may not emit source code as the RHS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%put` in macro language only prints items to the log. Instead, you want to use `putn()`.

```
%LET vmes = %sysfunc(putn(&i, z2.));
```